# Kashflow integration - object has no 'UseCustomDeliveryAddress' property when creating invoice

Tags: php, soap

I'm pretty new to Kashflow, but I am trying to integrate it into a CRM I have been working on. At the moment, I am trying to create an invoice and then use the InsertInvoice call to push it to Kashflow via the API.

This is the code I am using to create the test invoice:

```
$kashflow = new Kashflow($username,$password);

// Initialise the invoice.
$invoice  = new KashflowInvoice($kashflow_customer_id,$invoice_number,$invoice_date,$due_date);

// Add a line to the invoice: 1 unit, with a unit price of £10 @ 20% VAT.

$invoice->addLine(1,10,2,20,$nominal_id,"Test invoice item");

// Now insert the invoice on Kashflow.
$response = $kashflow->insertInvoice($invoice);
```

addLine() just adds the entry to the invoice and then insertInvoice() method is as follows:

```
public function insertInvoice(KashflowInvoice $invoice)
{
    $lines = $this->prepareInvoiceLines($invoice->getLines());

    $parameters['Inv'] = array
    (
          // parameters here...
    );

     return $this->makeRequest("InsertInvoice",$parameters);
}
```

Where all the "parameters" are the required ones from Kashflow.

When I run the script, I get the following exception output:

> Unhandled exception: SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object has no
>   'UseCustomDeliveryAddress' property

I have no property anywhere in my class or file called UseCustomeDeliveryAddress nor can I find it documented in the Kashflow API documentation - which makes me wonder if maybe it was deprecated but somewhere it's still being referenced?

Has anyone else come up against this issue and managed to solve it?

Thanks in advance
Michael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I figured it out. Basically the example I was using needed to have UseCustomDeliveryAddress passed to the API, regardless of whether it was true or false.

Referenced from https://securedwebapp.com/api/service.asmx?op=InsertInvoice